# Need help implementing CSS3 "glowing effect" to OceanWP menu bar in header and othe elements. Having trouble finding the correct selector

Tags: css, menu, css-animations

Been struggling for days to crack this code and add glowing effect to OceanWP menu. I'm new at CSS3 animations, so this has been stressful to say the very least. But, I'm determined to solve the problem. This is my first time asking for help, so please be gentle :)

The [url](https://pushfreedomfilms.com) to the site. Here's what I've tried recently. Most likely my selector is all wrong.

```html
#menu-main-menu{
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glow {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #e60073, 0 0 40px #e60073, 0 0 50px #e60073, 0 0 60px #e60073, 0 0 70px #e60073;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #ff4da6, 0 0 40px #ff4da6, 0 0 50px #ff4da6, 0 0 60px #ff4da6, 0 0 70px #ff4da6, 0 0 80px #ff4da6;
  }
}
```